# how to combine two mysql queries to show their results in one dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two table category and subcategory.In category table, i have one column  cat_url.In subcategory table, i have one column  sub_cat_url

What I want is to fetch all the URL of category table and subcategory table sorted alphabetically and show in menu dropdown

What i am doing is :

```
$A = "SELECT cat_url FROM category
WHERE cat_url like 'a%'

UNION ALL

SELECT sub_cat_url FROM subcategory
WHERE sub_cat_url like 'a%'
ORDER BY cat_url, sub_cat_url";

$rA = mysqli_query($dbc,$A) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

while ($rsA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rA)){ 

    <a href=".$rsA['cat_url'].'.php'.">

    echo $rsA['cat_url']; 

    // i do not want to use $rsA['cat_url']; What i need is to combine both cat_url and sub_cat_url in one result set and the echo each url

}
```

Comment: You want to display both table urls separately in drop down?

Comment: You should restructure your database. One table can hold both, cat and sub-cat. Create columns: url and parent. For cat set parent to 0, for sub-cat set parent to ID of cat. Much easier to maintain and query.

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya i want to display both table url in same drop down sorted  alphabatically

Comment: do you have any common field in both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to join the subcategory table like this (untested):

```
SELECT cat.cat_url as cat_url, subcat.sub_cat_url as sub_cat_url FROM category as cat
left join subcategory as subcat on subcat.sub_cat_url like 'a%'
WHERE cat.cat_url like 'a%' 
ORDER BY cat.cat_url, subcat.sub_cat_url
```

Comment: i am facing problem in  while ($rsA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rA)){

echo $rsA['cat_url'];  // THIS PART


}

Comment: what is the result of the query?

Comment: It is showing only one record from category table. I have trouble here  ($rsA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rA)){ echo $rsA['what to put here'];  }

Comment: can you print_r($rsA) and post the output?

Comment: output is Array ( [cat_url] => advocates-in-canada [sub_cat_url] => aoy-pg-in-canada )

Comment: As I understood is that a category has subcategories? or is subcategories not related to category?

Comment: Yes, You are correct ! Category has subcategory. Can we merge both cat_url and sub_cat_url in one array and then using foreach loop i can extract in one drop down menu. for reference you can check the menubar of this site [link](http://greaternoidaweb.com/). I will be in touch to you very soon nearly one hour. thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
select *
  from (
    SELECT cat_url as url FROM category WHERE cat_url like 'a%' 
    union all
    SELECT sub_cat_url as url FROM subcategory WHERE sub_cat_url like 'a%'
) a
order by url
```

Comment: It is giving result of subcategory table only.  $A = "select *  from ( SELECT cat_url as url FROM category WHERE cat_url like 'a%'  union   SELECT sub_cat_url as url FROM subcategory WHERE sub_cat_url like 'a%'
) a
order by url";

$rA = mysqli_query($dbc,$A) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
$rsA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rA);
print_r($rsA);

Comment: May i see ur tables data?

Comment: Thank you @maulik savaliya. I made an easy solution for this problem. I created a seperate table to store urls. During registration, url is inserted in that table either it is category or subcategory type, and now i am fetching from single column

Comment: @Rahulkumar great.